# Alpha particles and nitrogen triiodide

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

I've been reading [Wikipedia's article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitrogen_triiodide) on $\ce{NI_3}$ (which doesn't contain an $\ce{I_3^-}$ ion, so "nitrogen III iodide" [would probably be a better name for it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triiodide#Nomenclature)) and getting very confused. I'll start by distinguishing the decompositions$$\begin{align}2\ce{NI_3}&\to\ce{N_2}+3\ce{I_2},\\8\ce{NI_3NH_3}&\to5\ce{N_2}+6\ce{NH_4I}+9\ce{I_2},\end{align}$$since $\ce{NI_3}$ is often isolated or stored in the form $\ce{NI_3NH_3}$. Here are the two things I'm confused about:

- "Nitrogen triiodide was first characterized by Raman spectroscopy in 1990 when it was prepared by an ammonia-free route", despite at least one paper on experiments with nitrogen triiodide dating to 1958. I assume previous experiments were instead by the ammonia route.
- Now for the real mystery. Apparently, alpha radiation can trigger such a decomposition (according to Bowden 1958, so presumably it's the second reaction). Someone has earned a "citation needed" for adding, "several attempts to replicate this action have failed".

So here are my questions:

- How confident are we that alpha radiation has the claimed effect?
- What mechanism, be it purely theoretical or empirically mandated, has been proposed for such a decomposition? (See also my discussion below with @IvanNeretin of its attribution to the high KE of alpha particles.)

Comment: You have a rather distorted perspective of the whole "chemical vs nuclear" picture, as if looking at it from the wrong end of a telescope. Electronegativity of He does not matter. Charge on He does not matter (well, almost). Helium chemistry is not a part of the picture. What matters is the energy of an alpha particle, and the energy is really, _really_ big, and even bigger than that.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Are you saying the mechanism is that the alpha's multiple-MeV KE allows it to break covalent bonds? If so, does alpha radiation cause many materials to decompose?

Comment: Yes, very much so. It is just that your wording, while technically correct, is a massive understatement, as in _"High energy of a nuclear explosion may result in property damage, if performed indoors"_. Indeed, radiation of any type would gradually destroy many materials, and naturally, those which tend to _decompose by themselves_ are the most vulnerable.

Comment: @IvanNeretin OK, but how specifically do we expect energy to be redistributed among the nuclei and electrons? Will it primarily go to specific particles and thus trigger a particular reaction route, or are just about all options likely, dependent on just how the radiation strikes the target? In particular, do we expect the energy to be first delivered to an atom or a covalent bond?

Comment: A typical chemical bond is about 2-4eV. A Typical alpha particle has about 5,000,000eV KE (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_decay). You are asking "If somebody drops a nuke on my house can you tell me where the bricks will land"

Comment: @IanBush We _know_ where the bricks land; we know the products. It's more that I'm asking, "if non-identical bricks are linked by cement that obeys very complicated bond-specific quantum-mechanical rules, are there nontrivial constraints on how energy is dissipated?" A negative answer is far from obvious, if only because not only do alpha particles not routinely destroy everything, but doubt has been expressed this example even happens at all.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/107151/what-chemical-explosives-detonate-when-exposed-to-alpha-particles-or-nuclear-fis

Comment: Under what conditions could NI3 be used as an alpha detector?

Comment: @JamesGaidis It lacks essential attributes like easy operations, stability and recovery.